# Get information about LiveId (Office 365) account logged in Office application in VSTO AddIn

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto, office365, windows-live-id

I develop VSTO add-in for Word, Excel etc.
And I need to get information about user currently logged in Office application.
I need at least an email address.

[image]

I found these properties `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.UserName`, `.UserInitials` and `.UserAddress`. But it's not about `LiveID` account. It is about office user settings.

How can I get required information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one way to retrieve this information - read the Registry...
There are key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities\`
if it is Office 2016. There are subkey like `xxxxx_LiveId` where `xxxxx` matches to `ProviderId` value.

You can read at least `EmailAddress` value from that subkey.

So I wrote some C# code for retrieve an e-mail address of logged in LiveID user:

```
string GetUserEmailFromOffice365()
{
    string Version = "16.0"; //TODO get from AddIn
    string identitySubKey = $@"Software\Microsoft\Office\{Version}\Common\Identity\Identities";

    using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(identitySubKey))
    {
        if (key != null && key.SubKeyCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (var subkeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (var subkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey($@"{identitySubKey}\{subkeyName}"))
                    {
                        object value = null;
                        try
                        { 
                            value = subkey.GetValue("EmailAddress");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                        }
                        if (value != null && value is string)
                        {
                            return value as string;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Of cource you shouldn't hardcode `Version` value. You can get and remember office version from `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version` in `ThisAddIn.cs` file in `ThisAddIn_Startup` method.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Do you also happen to know how to get the identity for each document? Thus if a user has multiple documents opened in Word with each opened with another account.